# So, I have been writing a code on a messaging app in SwiftUi and I have a problem, that is "Cannot find auth in scope" here is the code(highlighted):

Tags: swiftui

Here is the error:

I have tried several ways but it's not working:

```
@State var LoginStatusMessage = ""

private func createNewAccount() {
    Auth.auth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) {
        result, err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to create user:", err)
            .self.errorMessage = "Failed to create user:Failed to create user: \(err)"
            return
        }
        
        print("Successfully created user: \(result?.user.uid ?? "")")
        
        self.LoginStatusMessage = "Successfully created user: \(result?.user.uid ?? "")"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using `Firebase`. First of all, you can't use `.auth` directly because it is a function, the right usage is this, [according to documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start)

```swift
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
  // ...
}
```

second of all, since the `swift` can't find `Auth` on scope, I also assume you did not import `FirebaseAuth`

so you have to add

```swift
import FirebaseAuth
```

to the beginning of your file.

Also, next time you're posting anything on StackOverFlow, please provide as much relevant detail as you can.